# Is there an R function for finding to parse correctly txt files?

Tags: r, text, unique

I have a test.txt file that has 7 headers. but not each row has 7 values.
My txt file was showing only 1 column and I used read.delim to separate the columns. But when I count the unique values per column I have a different output to what I am expecting

```r
df_test <-  read.delim("Test.txt", sep = "")
#c("ID", "colour", "skin", "eyes", "country", "name", "size"))
```

```r
testing <- unique(df_test$ID)

A tibble: 54 x 1
   testing                    
   <fct>                      
 1 EGA.0
 2 blue              
 3 green             
 4 ""                         
 5 V-alpha                    
 6 EGA.1
 7 EGA.2
 8 EGA.3
 9 EGA.4
10 EGA.5
```

I would like only values starting with EGA in my ID column. How do I fix this? How do I handle columns that do not have 7 values? I don't want a "colour" value in "ID"...

```r
testing <- unique(df_test$ID)

A tibble: 54 x 1
   testing                    
   <fct>                      
 1 EGA.0                  
 6 EGA.1
 7 EGA.2
 8 EGA.3
 9 EGA.4
10 EGA.5
```

Comment: Looks like the object name and column name is `testing`.  Is that right

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_detect`

```
library(tidyverse)
testing  %>%
    filter(str_detect(testing, "^EGA\\.\\d+"))
# A tibble: 6 x 1
#  testing
#  <fct>  
#1 EGA.0  
#2 EGA.1  
#3 EGA.2  
#4 EGA.3  
#5 EGA.4  
#6 EGA.5
```

#### data

```
testing <- structure(list(testing = structure(c(3L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("", "blue", "EGA.0", "EGA.1", "EGA.2", 
"EGA.3", "EGA.4", "EGA.5", "green", "V-alpha"), class = "factor")),
 row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Error: Result must have length 1720150, not 34541. I get this error. My unique values are 34541, altought should be less couse it is counting also non EGA strings.

Comment: @user11465312  I think your data is a vector.  Please chek

Comment: Column name is ID

Comment: @user11465312  IN that case use `str_detect(ID,`

Comment: I get this....:( no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: @user11465312  Try `filter(str_detect(as.character(ID), `

Comment: @user11465312  `testing <- unique(df_test$ID)`  Is the output you posted is for `testing`

Comment: @user11465312  I showed the data I used and the output I am getting

Comment: @user11465312 you should post `df_test` not just a column.

Comment: not sure how you get that structure or what 3L...etc means... thank you anyway :)

Comment: @user11465312  I used `dput(<yourdata>)`